# Using python and the bittorrent protocol

Tags: python, bittorrent

I wanted to write a program with could send and receive data over a NAT router without having to set up port forwarding first. Do i need to use the bittorrent protocol or is there something better?

Comment: You can use plain TCP if only one side is behind NAT, this side has to start the connection. If both sides are behind NAT you will need a relay that isn't.

Answer (score 2):

BitTorrent is not a NAT traversal technology but a P2P file sharing protocol. Unless you want to transfer files BitTorrent probably won't help much.

Some routers will let you setup a port mapping using UPnP. (see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294504/python-upnp-igd-client-implementation) to find a Python UPnP client library)

An alternative would be to setup Teredo tunneling on your machine. That will hopefully take care of NAT traversal and give you a *real* unfirewalled IPv6 address behind your IPv4 NAT router.